# Solve indeterminate equation system in R

Tags: r, solver, equation-solving

I have a equation system and I want to solve it using numerical methods. I want to get a close solution given a starting seed. Let me explain.

I have a vector of constants ,`X`, of values:

```
X <- (c(1,-2,3,4))
```

and a vector `W` of weights:

```
W <- (c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))
```

I want that the sum of the components of W will be (`sum(W)=1`), and the sum of the multiplication of `X` and `W` element by element will be a given number `N`   (`sum(W*X)=N`).

Is there a easy way to do this in R? I have it in Excel, using Solver, but I need to automatize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your constant and your target value:

```
x <- c(1, -2, 3, 4)
n <- 10
```

You need a function to minimize.  The first line contains each of your conditions, and the second line provides a measure of how to combine the errors into a single score.  You may want to change the second line.  For example, you could make one error term be more heavily weighted than the other using `sum(c(1, 5) * errs ^ 2)`.

```
fn <- function(w)
{
  errs <- c(sum(w) - 1, sum(x * w) - n) 
  sum(errs ^ 2)
}
```

The simplest thing is to start with all the weights the same value.

```
init_w <- rep.int(1 / length(x), length(x))
```

Use `optim` to optimize.

```
optim(init_w, fn)
## $par
## [1]  0.1204827 -1.2438883  1.1023338  1.0212406
## 
## $value
## [1] 7.807847e-08
## 
## $counts
## function gradient 
##      111       NA 
## 
## $convergence
## [1] 0
## 
## $message
## NULL
```

The `par` element contains your weights.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I guess one could also subjectively weight the importance of each value in `errs` for the minimization? e.g. `errs <- c(sum(w) - 1, sum(x * w) - n) * c(5,1)`

Comment: wow, amazing. Finally I understood how optim works properly. Thanks a lot. Very nice answer

Comment: @Marcinthebox Maybe semantically better to put the error weights in the next line where you combine them into a single score.  I've updated the answer to show how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no unique solution for this problem. If you try other initial values for `w` you will most likely get different results from `optim`.

The problem can be formulated as solving an underdetermined system of linear equations.

```
A <- matrix(c(rep(1,4),x), nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
b <- matrix(c(1,n), nrow=2)
```

We seek a solution that satisfies `A %*% w = b` but which one? Minimum norm solution? Or maybe some other one? There are infinitely many solutions. Solutions can be given using the pseudo-inverse of the matrix `A`. Use package `MASS` for this.

```
library(MASS)
Ag <- ginv(A)
```

The minimum norm solution is

```
wmnorm <- Ag %*% b
```

And check with `A %*% wmnorm - b` and `fn(wmnorm)`.
See the Wikipedia page [System of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations)
the section `Matrix solutions`.

The solutions are given by

```
Az <- diag(nrow=nrow(Ag)) - Ag %*% A
w <- wmnorm + Az %*% z
```

where `z` is an arbitrary vector of `ncol(Az)` elements.
And now generate some solutions and check

```
xb <- wmnorm
z <- runif(4)
wsol.2 <- xb + Az %*% z
wsol.2
A %*% wsol.2 - b
fn(wsol.2)

z <- runif(4)
wsol.3 <- xb + Az %*% z
wsol.3
A %*% wsol.2 - b
fn(wsol.3)
```

And you'll see that these two solutions are valid solutions when given as argument to `fn`. And are quite different from the solution found by `optim`. You could test this by choosing a different starting point `init_w` for example by `init_w1 <- runif(4)/4`.