# Nonlinear discrete optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, discrete-mathematics

I have a simple (indeed standard in economics) nonlinear constrained *discrete* maximisation problem to solve in R and am having trouble. I found solutions for *parts* of the problem (nonlinear maximisation; discrete maximisation) but not for the union of all the problems.

Here is the problem. A consumer wants to buy three products (ananas, banana, cookie), knows the prices and has a budget of 20€. He likes variety (i.e., he wants to have all three products if possible) and his satisfaction is decreasing in the amount consumed (he likes his first cookie way more than his 100th).

The function he wishes to maximise is

[image: function to maximize]

and of course since each has a price, and he has a limited budget, he maximises this function under the constraint that

[image]

What I want to do is to find the optimal buying list (N ananas, M bananas, K cookies) that satisfies the constraint.

If the problem were linear, I would simply use linprog::solveLP(). But the objective function is nonlinear.
If the problem were of a continuous nature, ther would be a simple analytic solution to it.

The question being discrete and nonlinear, I do not know how to proceed.

Here is some toy data to play with.

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c("ananas",2.17),c("banana",0.75),c("cookie",1.34)))
names(df) <- c("product","price")
```

I'd like to have an optimization routine that gives me an optimal buying list of (N,M,K).

Any hints?

Comment: Essentially what you need is a non-linear, inequality constrained, discrete optimizer which I don't believe it exists in R (yet). You could use `Rsolnp` that provides everything apart from the discrete case and then test all the combinations of the rounded up and down of the estimated values. If the parameters are too many then you could compromise by taking the rounded down values. In most cases it would still be an acceptable solution.

Comment: I wonder if there now exists such a package in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) no packages** This can be done by brute force.   Using `df` from the question as input ensure that `price` is numeric (it's a factor in the `df` of the question) and calculate the largest number `mx` for each variable.  Then create grid `g` of variable counts and compute the `total` price of each and the associated `objective` giving `gg`.  Now sort `gg` in descending order of objective and take those solutions satisfying the constraint.  `head` will show the top few solutions.

```
price <- as.numeric(as.character(df$price))
mx <- ceiling(20/price)
g <- expand.grid(ana = 0:mx[1], ban = 0:mx[2], cook = 0:mx[3]) 
gg <- transform(g, total = as.matrix(g) %*% price, objective = sqrt(ana * ban * cook))
best <- subset(gg[order(-gg$objective), ], total <= 20)
```

giving:

```
> head(best) # 1st row is best soln, 2nd row is next best, etc.
     ana ban cook total objective
1643   3   9    5 19.96  11.61895
1929   3   7    6 19.80  11.22497
1346   3  10    4 19.37  10.95445
1611   4   6    5 19.88  10.95445
1632   3   8    5 19.21  10.95445
1961   2  10    6 19.88  10.95445
```

**2) dplyr** This can also be nicely expressed using the dplyr package.  Using `g` and `price` from above:

```
library(dplyr)
g %>% 
  mutate(total = c(as.matrix(g) %*% price), objective = sqrt(ana * ban * cook)) %>%
  filter(total <= 20) %>%
  arrange(desc(objective)) %>%
  top_n(6)
```

giving:

```
Selecting by objective
  ana ban cook total objective
1   3   9    5 19.96  11.61895
2   3   7    6 19.80  11.22497
3   3  10    4 19.37  10.95445
4   4   6    5 19.88  10.95445
5   3   8    5 19.21  10.95445
6   2  10    6 19.88  10.95445
```

Comment: thanks. This is very good (I do not have strict computation time constraints, so brute force seems ok). I approved it because it can be easily turned into a function given any df. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind using a "by hand" solution:

```
uf=function(x)prod(x)^.5
bf=function(x,pr){
  if(!is.null(dim(x)))apply(x,1,bf,pr) else x%*%pr
}
budget=20
df <- data.frame(product=c("ananas","banana","cookie"),
                 price=c(2.17,0.75,1.34),stringsAsFactors = F)
an=0:(budget/df$price[1]) #include 0 for all possibilities
bn=0:(budget/df$price[2])
co=0:(budget/df$price[3])
X=expand.grid(an,bn,co)
colnames(X)=df$product
EX=apply(X,1,bf,pr=df$price)
psX=X[which(EX<=budget),] #1st restrict
psX=psX[apply(psX,1,function(z)sum(z==0))==0,] #2nd restrict
Ux=apply(psX,1,uf)
cbind(psX,Ux)
(sol=psX[which.max(Ux),])
uf(sol) # utility
bf(sol,df$price)  #budget
```

> ```
> > (sol=psX[which.max(Ux),])
>      ananas banana cookie
> 1444      3      9      5
> > uf(sol) # utility
> [1] 11.61895
> > bf(sol,df$price)  #budget
>  1444 
> 19.96
> ```

Comment: I think your solution of 3 ananas, 9 bananas, and 5 cookies sums to $28?

Comment: @Marcinthebox mmm nope, it looks to correctly sum to 19.96. I was also wondering why you have such a different result...

Comment: @PaoloCrosetto - was a bad loading of the dataframe on my part - you fixed the conversion of price to factor, while I messed up doing that. I now get the same result as you. Cheers, Marc

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is very similar in nature to this question ([Solve indeterminate equation system in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32625191/1199289)). The answer by Richie Cotton was the basis to this possible solution:

```
df <- data.frame(product=c("ananas","banana","cookie"),
                 price=c(2.17,0.75,1.34),stringsAsFactors = F)

FUN <- function(w, price=df$price){
  total <- sum(price * w) 
  errs <- c((total-20)^2, -(sqrt(w[1]) * sqrt(w[2]) * sqrt(w[3])))
  sum(errs)
}

init_w <- rep(10,3)
res <- optim(init_w, FUN, lower=rep(0,3), method="L-BFGS-B")
res
res$par # 3.140093 9.085182 5.085095
sum(res$par*df$price) # 20.44192
```

Notice that the total cost (i.e. price) for the solution is $ 20.44. To solve this problem, we can weight the error terms to put more emphasis on the 1st term, which relates to the total cost:

```
### weighting of error terms
FUN2 <- function(w, price=df$price){
  total <- sum(price * w) 
  errs <- c(100*(total-20)^2, -(sqrt(w[1]) * sqrt(w[2]) * sqrt(w[3]))) # 1st term weighted by 100
  sum(errs)
}

init_w <- rep(10,3)
res <- optim(init_w, FUN2, lower=rep(0,3), method="L-BFGS-B")
res
res$par # 3.072868 8.890832 4.976212
sum(res$par*df$price) # 20.00437
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not resort to rounding -> it is not an innocent thing to do, the results after rounding might be not optimal after all...

Comment: I've removed the rounding effect in the example now.

Answer (score 1):

As LyzandeR remarked there is no nonlinear integer programming solver available in R. Instead, you can use the R package *rneos* that sends data to one of the NEOS solvers and returns the results into your R process.

Select one of the solvers for "Mixed Integer Nonlinearly Constrained Optimization" on the [NEOS Solvers](http://neos.mcs.anl.gov/neos/solvers/) page, e.g., Bonmin or Couenne. For your example above, send the following files in the AMPL modeling language to one of these solvers:

[Note that maximizing the product  `x1 * x2 * x3`  is the same as maximising the product `sqrt(x1) * sort(x2) * sqrt(x3)`.]

Model file:

```
param p{i in 1..3};
var x{i in 1..3} integer >= 1;
maximize profit: x[1] * x[2] * x[3];
subject to restr: sum{i in 1..3} p[i] * x[i] <= 20;
```

Data file:

```
param p:= 1 2.17  2 0.75  3 1.34 ;
```

Command file:

```
solve;
display x;
```

and you will receive the following solution:

```
x [*] :=
1  3
2  9
3  5
;
```

This approach will work for more extended examples were solutions "by hand" are not reasonable and rounded `optim` solutions are not correct.

To look at a more demanding example, let me propose the following problem:

Find an integer vector x = (x_i), i=1,...,10, that maximizes  x1 * ... * x10, such that  p1*x1 + ... + p10*x10 <= 10, where  p = (p_i), i=1,...,10,  is the following price vector

```
p <- c(0.85, 0.22, 0.65, 0.73, 0.91, 0.11, 0.31, 0.47, 0.93, 0.71)
```

Using `constrOptim` for this nonlinear optimization problem with a *linear* inequality constraint, I get solutions like 900 for different starting points, but never the optimal solutions that is 960 !